# Bind ItemSource to listbox

Tags: c#, xaml

This question is probably asked many times before but I have seen so many answers I really dont know what to do.

I have a ListBox:

```
<listbox ItemSource="{Binding listitems}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <grid>
                <Textblock text="{Binding value1}">
                <Textblock text="{Binding value2}">
            </grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</listbox>
```

and I have a list of the following class:

```
List<Items> listitems = new List<Items>();
public class Items
{
    public string value1 { get; set; }
    public string value2 { get; set; }
}
```

Sometimes, the list gets updated (more elements added), and I want to let the listbox know the list is updated and update the UI accordingly.

At this moment I bind the list to the listbox in my c# manually, and when it changes, I clear the listbox and add the list again, which is not desired.

I wonder how the listbox can update automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of generic `List<T>`, use [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) which internally implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface responsible for updating elements on UI.

```
ObservableCollection<Items> listitems = new ObservableCollection<Items>();
```

**EDIT**

ListItems have to be `property`. You can't bind it with field -

```
ObservableCollection<Items> listitems = new ObservableCollection<Items>();
public ObservableCollection<Items> Listitems
{
   get
   {
      return listitems;
   }
   set
   {
      listItems = value;
   }
}
```

XAML -

```
<Listbox ItemSource="{Binding Listitems}">
```

Comment: You need to use property instead of field. See updated answer. You can't bind with field from XAML.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the `List` to `ObservableCollection` and implement everything according to the MVVM pattern.

```
public ObservableCollection<Items> Listitems 
{
    get { return _listitems ; }
    set
    {
        _listitems  = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => Listitems );
    }
}
```

The same thing you have to do for each of the properties in `Items`. Also use [Prism](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28950) for binding. You can find many nice tutorials online like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx)

Comment: Mm interesting , but is there any other way to do this without a MVVM pattern? The problem is my app is almost finished and this is one of my last steps..

Comment: Fixed it! But I will look into the Prism thing and use it in my next app :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using List then you have to notify using INotifypropertyChanged otherwise you can use ObservableCollection.

also have to use NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True.

Comment: When I use ObservableCollection<Items> listitems = new ObservableCollection<Items>(), the UI still doesn't update